# Multiply a list in python -- Confused on the question of the exercise

Tags: python, list

"Given an list of numbers, and a single factor (also a number), create a new list consisting of each of the numbers in the list multiplied by the factor"

Then print the new list.

Which I'm almost positive is not how they wanted the exercise done I'm just a bit confused by the question.. 
I'm not sure if they want say another variable that I work into the for loop, or what. 
Explanation would be nice. :)

My code:

```
numbers = [3, 4, 16, 12, -1]
empty_list=[]

for i in numbers: 
    empty_list.append(i * 3)
print (empty_list)
```

Comment: If the question is really that incomplete one can only guess what is missing.

Comment: Your question is cut off in the middle. Why not use `print(map(lambda x: x*n, lst))` To achieve what your code does?

Comment: @IsaacDj The exercises are list exercises, and they have yet to tell us anything about map, or anything like that which they aren't stopping us from using it but..

Comment: @MichaelButscher fixed the question I had accidentally cut some of it off..

Comment: What is the issue here, exactly? This looks fine to me.

Comment: @AMC I was thinking the same thing, but I figured maybe me being a starter that maybe they had meant something different like maybe have a variable that's a number which then multiplies each of the list's item in a for loop or something..

Comment: _have a variable that's a number which then multiplies each of the list's item in a for loop or something_ That's basically what you're currently doing though, no?

Comment: @AMC I had thought so.. but I mean it just seem's the same as an earlier exercise as where they asked for the sum of a list... maybe just a useless question I had asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your solution is definitely fine, anyhow here are a few different possible approaches to the question.

1 - the loop, as you did it:

```
def multiply_lst_1(lst,n):
    new_lst = []
    for val in lst:
        new_lst.append(val * n)
    print(new_lst)
    return new_lst
```

2 - list comprehension:

```
def multiply_lst_2(lst,n):
    new_lst = [n * val for val in lst]
    print(new_lst)
    return new_lst
```

3 - map:

```
def multiply_list_3(lst,n):
    new_lst = list(map(lambda x: n * x, lst))
    print(new_lst)
    return new_lst
```

Comment: `map(lambda x: n * x, lst)` Does that return a list?

Comment: Are you still using Python 2? `map()` returns a map object now. Use the list comprehension instead.

Comment: I'll just leave it as is, and if they had wanted it done a different way they can explain later on.. Preciate the other approaches!

Comment: @wjandrea still in the process of migrating

Answer (score 0):

List Comprehension is a better way to solve the problem, than to use a structred for loop, i.e.,

```
newlist = [i * factor for i in original_list]
```

is better than

```
for i in original_list:
   newlist.append(i * factor)
```

Additionally, pandas can be used to solve this problem as

```
n = pandas.Series(original_list)
newlist = (s * factor).tolist()
```

Numpy can also be used for this

```
lis = numpy.array(original_list)
newlist = lis * factor
```

You can also use map() function here

```
newlist = list(map((factor).__mul__, original_list))
```